# Angular cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am getting the following error

[image]
I am new to angular so not able to understand what it means. Could somebody please explain me what this means ?

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { EventManager, AlertService, LanguageService } from '../../util';

import { DataConfiguration } from './dataconfiguration.model';
import { DataConfigurationPopupService } from './dataconfiguration-popup.service';
import { DataConfigurationService } from './dataconfiguration.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'dp-dataconfiguration-dialog',
    templateUrl: './dataconfiguration-dialog.component.html'
})
export class DataConfigurationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    dataConfiguration: DataConfiguration;
    authorities: any[];
    isSaving: boolean;

    constructor(
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        private languageService: LanguageService,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private dataConfigurationService: DataConfigurationService,
        private eventManager: EventManager
    ) {
        this.languageService.setLocations(['dataconfiguration']);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.authorities = ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'];
    }
    clear () {
        this.activeModal.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    save () {
        this.isSaving = true;
        if (this.dataConfiguration.id !== undefined) {
            this.dataConfigurationService.update(this.dataConfiguration)
                .subscribe((res: DataConfiguration) => this.onSaveSuccess(res), (res: Response) => this.onSaveError(res.json()));
        } else {
            this.dataConfigurationService.create(this.dataConfiguration)
                .subscribe((res: DataConfiguration) => this.onSaveSuccess(res), (res: Response) => this.onSaveError(res.json()));
        }
    }

    private onSaveSuccess (result: DataConfiguration) {
        this.eventManager.broadcast({ name: 'dataconfigurationListModification', content: 'OK'});
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.activeModal.dismiss(result);
    }

    private onSaveError (error) {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.onError(error);
    }

    private onError (error) {
        this.alertService.error(error.message, null, null);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'dp-dataconfiguration-popup',
    template: ''
})
export class DataConfigurationPopupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    modalRef: NgbModalRef;
    routeSub: any;

    constructor (
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private dataConfigurationPopupService: DataConfigurationPopupService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            if ( params['id'] ) {
                this.modalRef = this.dataConfigurationPopupService
                    .open(DataConfigurationDialogComponent, params['id']);
            } else {
                this.modalRef = this.dataConfigurationPopupService
                    .open(DataConfigurationDialogComponent);
            }

        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"
                (click)="clear()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myDataConfigurationLabel" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.home.createOrEditLabel">Create or edit a DataConfiguration</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <dp-alert-error></dp-alert-error>
        <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!dataconfiguration.id">
            <label for="id" dpTranslate="global.field.id">ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id"
                   [(ngModel)]="dataconfiguration.id" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.name" for="field_name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="field_name"
                [(ngModel)]="dataconfiguration.name"
            required minlength="3" />
            <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.name?.dirty && editForm.controls.name?.invalid)">
                <small class="form-text text-danger"
                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.name?.errors?.required" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.validation.required">
                   This field is required.
                </small>
                <small class="form-text text-danger"
                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.name?.errors?.minlength" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.validation.minlength" translateValues="{ min: 3 }">
                   This field is required to be at least 3 characters.
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="clear()">
            <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>&nbsp;<span dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="editForm.form.invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="fa fa-save"></span>&nbsp;<span dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.action.save">Save</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

index.ts

```
export * from './tenant.model';
export * from './tenant-popup.service';
export * from './tenant.service';
export * from './tenant-dialog.component';
export * from './tenant-delete-dialog.component';
export * from './detail/tenant-detail.component';
export * from './tenant.component';
export * from './tenant.route';
export * from './configuration/dataconfiguration.service';
export * from './configuration/dataconfiguration-popup.service';
export * from './configuration/dataconfiguration-dialog.component';
export * from './configuration/dataconfiguration-delete-dialog.component';
export * from './configuration/detail/dataconfiguration-detail.component';
```

Comment: Take a look to your file index.ts at line 15. You are trying to read a property replace on a variable that's not defined.

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: update the code in the relevant files without which this cannot be fixed

Comment: @MilanRaval HTML posted

Comment: @mickdev index.ts posted. It has only 13 lines.

Comment: Maybe you have some space between every lines in the original file. In your editor, you have nothing at line 15 at all ? So you should identify the file that trigger the error and try to fix it or post it maybe someone else will see what you are missing.

Comment: okay found the issue. In my route.ts file i tried to import using dataConfiguration and not by dataconfiguration. Just capital C made a whole lots of diff :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay found the issue. In my route.ts file i tried to import using dataConfiguration and not by dataconfiguration. Just capital C made a whole lots of diff :))

That means the files imports are case sensitive so be careful when you do imports.
Somehow the error should be more simple. I never understand javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please search for replace in your whole project, I'm guessing one of the services has a replace in an asynchronous function, which is called within your source code above, but resides somewhere else.

I had these types of error, when I used this insides a Promise (returned by my service). I just got TypeErrors until I realized, that I have to var other = this; before the return of a new Promise and use other insead of this throughout the Promise functions.

Comment: Is there is a way i can debug and see

Comment: AH i see in the comment above, you found the issue, please post a complete answer instead of only a comment.